# injecting CSS changes with chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing some custom chrome extensions to reformat certain sites.  I'm having lots of luck with simply hiding things, however I've run into a problem trying to adjust a right-margin on something.  Viewing the HTML results in the following:

```
<div id="bodyContent2" class="en">
```

In the styles area of the Chrome development tools I see

```
#bodyContent2.en {
  margin-right: 330px;
  min-height: 920px;
  width: auto;
}
```

If I manually change that to margin-right: 0px; with Chrome it does exactly what I want.  However, the following lines of CSS do not work when called from my manifest.json file in my extension:

```
#bodyContent2 {margin-right:0px;}
[id='bodyContent2']{margin-right:0px;}
#bodyContent2 .en {margin-right:0px;}
.en {margin-right:0px;}
```

None of them work and I don't understand why not.  I literally just started working with chrome extensions today.  Help is much appreciated.  In the individual attempts I see the following CSS striked through in the chrome dev tools:

```
#bodyContent2 {
    <strike>margin-right: 0px;</strike>
}
.en {
   <strike>margin-right: 0px;</strike>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `!important` to your rules to give them higher priority:

```
margin-right:0px !important;
```

If you want to understand the order in which css rules are applied read about [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).